# Allow user to withdraw money from their account from my portal

Tags: php, paypal

I am creating a portal when user can pay money and purchase product. They can even create account and transfer money to that account via paypal for instant purchase.Now I want to allow them to withdraw remaining amount from their account. I have tried `Mass-pay paypal classic api`, but It is not allowing me to pay my users in different country. My store's default currency is **Euro**. Does any one have better solution for withdraw amount via paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Paypal adaptive payment for sending money

Check following links

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/